# Python list building

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to build a function for a grocery list from a .txt file, which looks like this:

```
milk
cheese

bread
hotdog buns

chicken
tuna
burgers
```

and so on.  From the list above, my grocery list should look like `[['milk', 'cheese'], ['bread', 'hotdog buns'], ['chicken', 'tuna', 'burgers']]`, so a list of lists in which items are separated when there is a space between them in the text file.

I have to use `.readline()`, and I can't use `.readlines(), .read()`, or the `for` loop.  My code right now creates an empty list:

```
def grocery_list(foods):
    L = open(foods, 'r')
    food = []
    sublist = []
    while L.readline() != '':
        if L.readline() != '\n':
            sublist.append(L.readline().rstrip('\n'))
        elif L.readline() == '\n':
            food.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
    return food
```

I don't know where it goes wrong so it returns a fully empty list.  I'm also not sure about the `''` and `'\n'` part; the example test file I'm using, when opened in the shell, looks like this:

```
milk\n
cheese\n
\n
...
''
''
```

but does `.rstrip()` or the whole `!= ''` make sense for every list?  Or am I just not even on the right track?

Comment: *I have to use .readline(), and I can't use .readlines(), .read(), or the for loop.* Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that you aren't adding the final `sublist` to the result. As @Xymostech mentioned, you need to capture the result of each call to `readline()` as the next call will be different. Here is how I would modify your code.

```
def grocery_list(foods):
    with open(foods, 'r') as L:        
        food = []            
        sublist = []            

        while True:
            line = L.readline()
            if len(line) == 0:
                break

            #remove the trailing \n or \r
            line = line.rstrip()

            if len(line) == 0:
                food.append(sublist)
                sublist = []                    
            else:
                sublist.append(line)
        if len(sublist) > 0:
            food.append(sublist)

        return food
```

Pay attention to the use of the `with` statement. This ensures that the file is closed after it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code as below, to achieve what you wanted:

```
def grocery_list(foods):
    with open(foods,'r') as f:
        food=[]
        sublist=[]
        while True:
            line=f.readline()
            if len(line)==0:
                break
            if line !='\n':
                sublist.append(line.strip())
            else:
                food.append(sublist)
                sublist=[]
        food.append(sublist)
    return food
```

Answer (score 2):

A little neater, in my opinion. Another option to achieve the results you require.

```
def grocerylist(foods):  
  with open(foods) as f:
    line = f.readline()
    items = []
    while line:
      items.append(line.rstrip())
      line = f.readline()
    newlist = [[]]
    for item in a:
      if not x: newlist.append([])
      else: newlist[-1].append(x)
    return newlist
```

`newlist` now contains the following:

```
[['milk', 'cheese'], ['bread', 'hotdog buns'], ['chicken', 'tuna', 'burgers']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call L.readline(), you're reading in another line. You should be storing the value of it the first time, and using that value in each of the next statements.

Comment: L = open(foods, 'r')
    food = []
    sublist = []
    item = L.readline()
    while item != '':
        if item != '\n':
            sublist.append(item.rstrip('\n'))
        elif item == '\n':
            food.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
        return food

and it does the same thing (empty list).  Is that what you mean?